# Terrell "rotation": should wikipedia be corrected?

Tags: special-relativity

There are two common misconceptions regarding the Terrell "rotation" :

1. it's a pure rotation
2. the Lorentz-Fitzgerald contraction is not detectable by a single detector, in which the past light-cone of the detector intersects with the history of a relativistic object. Instead, the detector sees a purely rotated object, with no contraction.

**Both of these assertions are false**. See the papers below for reference.

These errors have propagated for many years.
For example see the quotation referenced [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/517686/length-contraction-in-special-relativity-causes-an-object-to-appear-rotated-in-s).

In order to correct that, **shouldn't the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation) on the topic be amended in order to clarify these two points?**

---

1965
The geometrical appearance of large objects moving at relativistic speeds
G.D. Scott, M. R. Viner  (University of Toronto)
Am. J. Phys. 33, 534-536 (1965)
https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1971890
Bibcode: 1965AmJPh..33..534S

*"The calculated geometrical appearance of objects moving at relativistic speeds and subtending large angles at
the observer is illustrated by diagrams of a plane grid and perspective views of a group of boxes. In addition to
the distortion of scales in the direction of motion, planes perpendicular to the motion appear as hyperboloids.
Contrary to an impression which might be taken from some papers on the subject, the Lorentz contraction is visible
under suitable conditions, in particular for observations approximately at right angles to the motion."*
also:
*"... the explanation of the appearance in terms of a rotation is quite inadequate."*

---

1970
Geometrical Appearances at Relativistic Speeds
G. D. Scott, H. J. van Driel, University of Toronto
Am. J. Phys. vol 38 No. 8 August 1970
https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1976550

*"Geometrical appearances at relativistic speeds (β=0.5,0.9,and 0.995) are illustrated for the following examples:
(i) the celestial sphere with a number of constellations, (ii) the surface features of a sphere passing close to an observer,
and (iii) a train of rectangular boxes. The figures make clear the nature of the distortions which occur in appearances,
indicate the limited significance of the so-called 'apparent rotation', and show the conditions under which the Lorentz
contraction can be seen or photographed. Though a sphere remains essentially circular in outline, the apparent cross
section may be grossly distorted and under some conditions the outside surface of the sphere appears concave."*

---

1972 On the Apparent Visual Forms of Relativistically Moving Objects
P. M. Mathews, M. Lakshmanan (University of Madras)
Nuovo Cimento B, Vol. 12B, Ser. 11, p. 168 - 181, 11-November-1972
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02895571
http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02895571
Bibcode: 1972NCimB..12..168M

*"The question of the apparent visual shape of an object moving at relativistic speeds, as perceived by a single observer,
is analysed afresh. It is shown by qualitative arguments that the apparent shape is related to the shape at rest through a
combination of nonuniform shear and extension/contraction parallel to the direction of motion, which does not reduce to a
rotation even in the case of distant objects subtending a small angle at the observer. The two-dimensional projection
(as in a photograph) of this distorted shape may coincide with that of the object (suitably rotated) at rest; but we
emphasize that it would be grossly misleading to conclude from this, as is generally done in the literature, that distant
relativistically moving objects appear as if simply rotated. The 'train paradox' is discussed in illustration of this point.
Analytical formulae relating the apparent visual shape to the shape at rest are given. Also the striking fact that the
apparent speed of the object as seen by visual observation may well exceed the speed of light is brought out. Finally it is
pointed out that the phenomenon is closely analogous to the relativistic Doppler effect."*
[They correct Terrell, saying it's not a pure rotation, but nonuniform shear + extension/contraction, even in the
case of small solid angle.]

---

1988 The twists and turns of the Terrell effect
Eric Sheldon (University of Lowell)
American Journal of Physics 56, 199 (1988); https://doi.org/10.1119/1.15687 full text
(letter to the editor)

He corrects 'rotation' to 'shear', 'a skew twist'. He points to Weisskopf's error about pure rotation,
and subsequent corrections by Scott-van Driel and Mathews-Lakshmanan.

Comment: Shouldn't you ask this on the article's talk page rather than here? There have been several edits to the article today (as of the time I write this). Are they your edits?

Comment: Yes, I added references to papers.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I have added a remark to the article's Talk page.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics, but about the content of another website, which has its own rules, and which should in any case never be regarded as authoritative.

Comment: Could the question be amended in a way that would be acceptable? For instance, could it be rephrased as "do you agree that these are misconceptions about this effect?"

Comment: @JohnO:  That would probably be closed as "opinion-based".

Answer (score 0):

Terrell "rotation" works conveniently as a description for spherical objects only.  The effect of seeming to see "behind" things that are "in front" of you is a simple combination of two things:

1. You are looking directly *at* the image you are seeing, and
2. Your vision is distorted by aberration, which makes things "level" with you appear to be thrown forward.

For the *special case* of a sphere, this has the apparent "effect" of rotation,  I am using the mathematics from [here](https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s2-05/2-05.htm), and I have used them to create my own videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvGnzGhIWTGR-O332xj0sToA0Yk1X7IuI) (please view in 1080 resolution, and read the descriptive text; there is a lot going on!).

Comment: It doesn't even work well for spherical objects. Only the outline remains spherical. Reference: Geometrical Appearances at Relativistic Speeds, G. D. Scott, H. J. van Driel, Am. J. Phys. vol 38 No. 8 August 1970 https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1976550

Comment: OK, I shall take your word for it, since I cannot afford to read the articles myself ;)